# How to set the same length between paragraphs when there is a verbatim box?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, paragraphs, knitr, sweave

What I want is to have 1em of distance between the paragraph and the verbatim box and 1em after the verbatim box and the next paragraph. I am using Rstudio with Knitr and PDFLatex. This is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parskip}{-1em}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim{\small\@verbatim \frenchspacing\@vobeyspaces \@xverbatim}
\preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=-1em \partopsep=-1em}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

<<>>=
head(mtcars, 3)
@

\lipsum[1]
```

This works great if I remove the `\setlength{\parskip}{1em}` command, but I need to have space between my paragraphs.

[image: equalize length between verbatim and paragraphs]

**UPDATE**

What I had to do was understand which environment knitr works in and then with a conditional set some parameters to adjust vertical space. It is not totally clear to me everything, since in this solution that I found, I am mixing the spacing with `\vspace`

Although there are also other solutions a little easier to implement, none included an example to have space between normal paragraphs as I defined it with `\parskip = 0.125in`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\parskip = 0.125in
% \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\ifdefined\knitrout
  \renewenvironment{knitrout}{

    \setlength{\parskip}{0ex} 
    \topsep=0ex             
    \partopsep=-0.5ex         
    \vspace{0.8ex}   
                     
    
  }{
     \vspace{-0.6ex} 
                     
  }
\else
\fi

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

<<>>=
head(mtcars)
@

\lipsum[2-3]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. The code you provided does not compile

Comment: Hello, yes, I suppose it is because I put a code snippet in R. I will have to think about how to simulate a box with verbatim to represent my problem and that it is possible to reproduce it without the need to use Rstudio, R and Sweave.

Comment: And because there are not end of the document.

Comment: A negative  `\parskip`, `\tosep` and `\partopsep` ? This is not a preamble, but a black hole! Just clean that convoluted preamble and if this is not enough for you (because default `\topsep` is not `1em`  but `10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 6.0pt`),  just set `\topsep`  to `1em`  (positive), but at the end of day could be not  a good idea avoid the flexibility of vertical spacers.

Comment: I added an update with a solution. In the above I forgot to put the `\end{document}`. I'm sorry. In this I think I use the flexibility of vertical spaces a little more.